# How to remove frame title from only a single slide within a frame, including vertical spacing/placeholder

Tags: beamer

#### Question

Is there a way to temporarily completely remove the frame title from a *single* slide of a given frame? By completely remove, I mean the vertical space for the title as well.

#### What I've tried

I tried using the `\begin{frame}{\only<...>{...}}` technique, but it preserves the vertical spacing.

#### Reason

Midway through one of my slides while I'm deep within a `itemize` environment with overlay specifications, I want to display a large full-screen figure. During this full-screen part, I want the frame title to be non-existent (as if it were specified with `\frame{}`). After the full-screen image, I want the title and the rest of itemization to reappear.

I can implement all of this except removing the frame title from a single slide.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}[t]{Frame number 1}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is frame number 1. 
            Compare the vertical placement of this itemize environment 
            to that on the next frame.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}[t]{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is frame number 2. Note that this second frame has no vertical space for the title.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}[t]{\only<1,3>{Frame number 3}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item <1-> I want the title showing on this slide, as it does.
        \item <2-> I want the title completely gone here, 
            including the vertical space it occupies. 
            (In my actual presentation, there will be a full-screen 
            figure in this position, 
            and the itemize environment will disappear.
        \item <3-> I want the title to come back
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well I suppose I should have tried for another 10 minutes.

I solved the issue by using surrounding a `\frametitle` command within an `\only` command. (In an earlier attempt, I reversed the nesting, which obviously didn't work.

Here it is in action:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}[t]{Frame number 1}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is frame number 1. 
            Compare the vertical placement of this itemize environment 
            to that on the next frame.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}[t]{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is frame number 2. Note that this second frame has no vertical space for the title.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}[t]{}
    \only<1,3>{\frametitle{Frame number 3}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item <1-> I want the title showing on this slide, as it does.
        \item <2-> I want the title completely gone here, 
            including the vertical space it occupies. 
            (In my actual presentation, there will be a full-screen 
            figure in this position, 
            and the itemize environment will disappear.
        \item <3-> I want the title to come back
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following inserts a full-frame image only for the second slide:

```
  \only<2>{% On the second slide...
    \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{% Add a picture to the ForeGround for this slide only
      \AtPageCenter{% At the center of the page/slide
        \makebox[0pt]{% Horizontally center image on slide
          \raisebox{-.5\height}{% Vertically center image on slide
            \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }
```

You can place this anywhere on the `frame` code that it applies to.

Here is your minimal example with the above code added:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame number 1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is frame number 1. 
      Compare the vertical placement of this itemize environment 
      to that on the next frame.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is frame number 2. Note that this second frame has no vertical space for the title.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{\only<1,3>{Frame number 3}}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item <1-> I want the title showing on this slide, as it does.
    \item <2-> I want the title completely gone here, 
      including the vertical space it occupies. 
      (In my actual presentation, there will be a full-screen 
      figure in this position, 
      and the itemize environment will disappear.
    \item <3-> I want the title to come back
  \end{itemize}

  \only<2>{% On the second slide...
    \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{% Add a picture to the ForeGround for this slide only
      \AtPageCenter{% At the center of the page/slide
        \makebox[0pt]{% Horizontally center image on slide
          \raisebox{-.5\height}{% Vertically center image on slide
            \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }
\end{frame}
```